# Animation text in a snake way with canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, canvas

I find this website -> http://bit.ly/1FCtQSQ and he has this animation scroll, which I am not interested, however in the middle of the scroll animation, a text snake animation appears. I want very badly to know how I can do this, just to learn.

I researched all plugins that curve texts, such as:

[Arctext.js](http://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/)
[CircleType](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDAQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcircletype.labwire.ca%2F&ei=vB1dVaipO8eVNvrqgZgM&usg=AFQjCNGokRCFyDp6NNMoQHfMwGdqQTW1xA&bvm=bv.93756505,d.eXY)
[This one](http://heygrady.com/blog/2011/07/20/animating-with-curves-in-jquery/)

Also, i tried 'still' the code from http://bit.ly/1FCtQSQ, but is minified, i know this guys are using the timelinemax, which uses the canvas, i tried to copy the code, but didn't work, as you can see here in the bottom of this question.

So i came here as the last resource.

Could someone give me an explanation with a working example, or maybe a plugin which i can study the code?

I know this is not the best way to find a answer to my question, but i don't have money to pay for codementor, hackhands, airpair or something like this.

Thanks!

Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJjjxG

Code that i copy:

```
<h1 class="snake">Animate this like a snake!</h1>

var animation = new TimelineMax({
    paused: !0,
    ease: Linear.easeNone
});
var T = 0;
var f = 30;

animation.add(
  TweenMax.to(e(".snake").parent(), f, {
        left: -5e3
}), T);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The KonvaJS (formerly KineticJS) canvas library has some nice text-along-path code with a liberal MIT license:

https://github.com/konvajs/konva/blob/f6e2cf19a30dec2f94f50152f20c35988b1bf99e/src/plugins/TextPath.js

The KonvaJS TextPath code works like this:

- Start with a path made up of curves and lines defined using the same syntax that SVG uses to define path.
- Calculate waypoints along that path.
- Fit characters one-by-one along the path using the calculated waypoints.
- Use transformations to position the characters properly. (using  `context.translate` & `context.rotate` to match the letter to the angle of the path / curve.)

You can cause the text to animate along the curve by beginning the text further & further beyond the first waypoint on the curve.

[image]

**Example code using the KonvaJS libarary:**

```js
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: 1000,
  height: 1000
});
var layer = new Konva.Layer();
// add the layer to the stage
stage.add(layer);

var textpath = new Konva.TextPath({
  x: 0,
  y: 50,
  fill: '#333',
  fontSize: 16,
  fontFamily: 'Arial',
  text: 'Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their party -- An phrase from an old touch-typing test.',
  data: 'M 100 200  C 200 100 300 0 400 100   C 500 200 600 300 700 200  C 800 100 900 100 900 100'
});

layer.add(textpath);
layer.draw();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/0.9.0/konva.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I'm very thankful for your answer since you were the only one who was interested in helping me, but i need ask, is possible to animate like a snake using the Konva library?

Comment: KonvaJS provides static (unanimated) text, but you can fairly easily get the text to animate. The simplest way is to add an increasing number of space-characters at the front of the text. This will push the text further along the path. You get animation by adding the spaces inside an animation loop.  More importantly, you mention you are interested in studying the source code. When you do you will find you can directly animate the text along the curve by starting the text at a waypoint further along the curve. Happy learning!